# ahref link simulate and triggering keypress/keydown

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

what im doing is when i click a link, it will trigger an keypress.
For example, when I click a link, it will actually do ctrl + = which is keycode 17 and 187 together. I have try but no luck,unsuccessful.

```
var press = jQuery.Event("keydown");
press.ctrlKey = true;
press.which = 187;
$("#resize").click(function(e){
    e.trigger(press);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

or anyone have a better way to do this ??

thanks

Comment: Instead of using `e` in your resize click event handler shouldn't you be using `this`?

Comment: Is your question answered? Then mark it as it is ;-)

Comment: opss ,sorry :D thanks your effort...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Triggering an event on an event will never work ;-) Use a selector instead:

```
var press = jQuery.Event("keydown");
press.ctrlKey = true;
press.which = 187;
$("#resize").click(function(e){
    $(document).trigger(press);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

[demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/XwjfB/2)

**Update**

Since the questioner has become a bit more [precise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14755513/ahref-link-simulate-and-triggering-keypress-keydown/14755829#comment20652726_14755829). I've made this **[demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/XwjfB/6/)**

This would be enough for his needs: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XwjfB/8/)

```
var i = 1;
$("#resize").click(function(e){
    $(document.body).css({transform: 'scale(' + (i += 0.1) + ')'});
    // or without css3, maybe:
    // $(document.body).css({zoom: i += 0.1});
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: its not working for me , my id for resize , it is href ,is that related?

Comment: @Nich No it isn't! Which browser do you use?

Comment: im using chrome v 24.0.1312.57 m, both of my mozila ,IE and chrome also dint work as well @@ i do alert something inside the func, and it actually goes into the func

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: erm, is working when i tried to alert it. but the problem is it dont actually resize the browser although the event is triggered, any prob occuring there? it should be resize the screen

Comment: That's not possible how you try it... You can't trigger browser-based-interactions... (Same as if you try to write text in an input field, will even not work) You've to *recreate* the zoom via javascript...

Comment: ah? is not possible to do it to resize the browser zoom?? because it saw a tutorial doing fullscreen ,so i tot it can be done too. http://davidwalsh.name/fullscreen ,no others solution to zoom the browser?

Comment: but when it zoom, suppose it can scroll to see the div,but it cannot see the div once i zoom..n i hav no idea mine cant work ,mayb im using gridster? so it cant see the size scale? erm...